# How to retrieve User-defined Timezone's Localtime using sys.time_zone_info

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timezone, dst

The application allows users to define their time zone
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU4ql.png).

But in [SQL Server, time_zone_info](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/sql-server/how-to-convert-utc-to-local-time-zone-in-sql-server) is not the timezone selected by user.

- So how could we map/relate the user defined time zone with the system table (which cater for DST)
- By leverage on `sys.time_zone_info`, how can we write the SQL to take DST into consideration?

e.g. 20 Mar - 30 Jun 2021: Due to DST, SQL should auto move 1 hr
forward (SQL will smartly push 1 hr forward); 1st Jul onwards: the same
SQL will push 1 hr backward

here is the SQL i use (but user are not selecting these timezone options, but rather (UTC+7 Beijing Time..)

```
declare @utc_date datetime = getdate()
select @utc_date as utc_time_zone, 
  getdate() at time zone 'US Eastern Standard Time' as time_zone_est,
  GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time' as x,
   CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), getdate(), 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' 
  ;
```

Comment: Use the [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) datatype?

Comment: @DaleK how to cross reference "UTC+8:00 Taipei" with 'Taipei Standard Time' from sys.time_zone_info? also, what is the table name store list of items from my first screenshot.

Comment: Capturing and storing UTC seems to be the easiest method for me... it is the "Great Equalizer".   It is a small matter to convert to local time on the client.

Comment: IMO it's almost always better to capture and store datetimes in UTC and perform any time zone translations in the client software. If you try to use `datetimeoffset` to store local time and offset, for example, it doesn't tell you what the user's time zone actually is - only the current UTC offset. i.e.: Is UTC+0800 in China, Nothern Asia, Singapore, Taipei, Ulaanbaatar or Western Australia? What time should be displayed in six month's time when Daylight Savings Time may have turned on or off? Storing UTC in the database and leaving time zones as a presentation issue simplifies many things.